# Windows 10 - RAID5 - Intel RAID or Storage Spaces?

Tags: windows-10, raid, software-raid, hardware-raid

Which method should I use to RAID5 my 3 drives?

At the moment I started out with Intel's RAID but it seems super slow. Steam can barely download with 10M/s speeds and the array sometimes have 3000ms+ response times while under load.

**Would the Windows provided RAID options be better/faster?**
And if so, which RAID option should I choose? Storage Spaces or the normal Disk Management?

The Intel RAID controller is a Z87 motherboard.

Ps.: I am aware of RAID5's write speed hit but this seems a bit excessive. My RAIDZ1 server writes/reads super fast compared to my local PC. So I was wondering if it's my controller. And I picked my motherboard's controller because online articles said the Intel Raid could be faster BUT I realize those articles might have used better, newer controllers, since my chipset is rather old.

Comment: How big is your array? RAID5 has very limited use cases now - have you considered raid 1 or 10 instead?

Comment: @davidgo - It is 3pcs of 3TB drives. I realize adding +1 and making a RAID10 array would make sense, but that'd require me buying several SATA cables, sata power cables  (to convert 4-pin to sata), a new PC case (no more slots/space anywhere), etc. It'd be just a fortune to just add that one more drive.

Comment: You are aware that you are running raid5 out of spec? The risk of failure of a second drive during a rebuild is very high. RAID5 effectively died at 2tb disks. If you think "the case +cables" (us$100 +labour?) is a fortune, your data is not valuable enough for RAID5. Drop to 2 disks (jbod if you have to, but raid1 is better) and put the third disk into backing up - RAID is not backup.

Comment: @davidgo - I run Backblaze over the array, and it's also on B2. It's more than safe, but sometimes my international bandwidth is lacking and it';s just way easier to have it all local. Thank you for the concern though, I realize RAID is no backup at all - heck I used RAID0 before this. Ha.